# Certain users see 404 when logging in

Tags: 9

We are seeing an odd error with certain users who are trying to log in to a Drupal 9 site. They are using the login form at /user/login, at which point they submit and are redirected to a URL like:

```
/user/form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvY....
```

Which results in a 404.

This only happens to 2 out of 20 users. If I use Drush to generate a login link, it works fine.

What could be causing this? There isn't much installed besides Pathauto, Token, Redirect, and Acquia Site Studio.

Answer (score 1):

`form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM` is used as placeholder for the action URL (for submitting the form).

If you still see this placeholder in the browser HTML source then the placeholder somehow got separated from the attached lazy builder. To debug this you could start with a form alter hook, where you see the placeholder string and the attached lazybuilder callback [FormBuilder::renderPlaceholderFormAction](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3ArenderPlaceholderFormAction). Go step by step through the render pipeline and check for custom code or templates which doesn't render the entire form as it should to carry on attached metadata.

Comment: Acquia is saying this is because of BigPipe combined with Site Studio. We aren't using Site Studio in any way on the user login form and no other modifications to that form have been made. Is BigPipe truly the culprit here? It would be the first time I have ever encountered this with BigPipe. How could it be resolved if it is in fact BigPipe (besides turning it off, of course)?

Comment: Form tokens are not handled by BigPipe, only the HTML tag styled placeholders used for render arrays.

Comment: Tested /user/login. If you are logged out BigPipe is disabled (works only with sessions). If you are logged in and display the form by other means, BigPipe is active, but doesn't deliver the form token, because non HTML tag styled tokens are excluded from BigPipe and are replaced on the server. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21big_pipe%21src%21Render%21Placeholder%21BigPipeStrategy.php/function/BigPipeStrategy%3A%3AdoProcessPlaceholders